# Use factoryboy with parametrized tests

Tags: python, pytest

I have 2 fixtures based on factoryboy sqlalchemy model fabrics:

```py
# conftest.py

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def location_type(type_factory):
    return type_factory.create(name='location')


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def booking_item_type(type_factory):
    return type_factory.create(name='booking_item')
```

I want to check if both of my types were created in db:

```py
# test_*.py file

def test_location_type_exists(db_session):
    assert db_session \
        .query(Type) \
        .filter(Type.name == 'location') \
        .count() == 1

def test_booking_item_type_exists(db_session):
    assert db_session \
        .query(Type) \
        .filter(Type.name == 'booking_item') \
        .count() == 1
```

It works fine, tests pass.

But I want to transform two tests to one parametrized test:

```py
@pytest.mark.parametrize('name', ['location', 'booking_item'])
def test_type_exist(db_session, name):
    assert db_session \
        .query(Type) \
        .filter(Type.name == name) \
        .count() == 1
```

I got one passed and one failed test with error `AssertionError: assert 2 == 1`. Why does it work this way? I expected the same result like the first case.

Comment: my assumption is the mixture of the `fixtures` with the use of one parametrized function. because `parametrize` creates two test invocations from your inputs and your `fixtures` declare `auto-use` on them, after the first test run of `location` they run again and add another row to throw the `count` off as you see. this is probably due to `db_session` not being reset between the parametrized runs. Can you try resetting `db_session` at the end of your test to see if it produces the desired results?

Comment: @gold_cy thank you, I added yield with closing session in db_session fixture and it works

Comment: you’re welcome, glad it worked out for you